# Young slit conundrum - Finding positions of maxima when one of the slits emanates light with phase difference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, double-slit-experiment, interference, diffraction

Second guessing myself a bit here, but I've run into a bit of an issue.

The problem I'm trying to solve is this:

> Coherent light of $532nm$ is passing through a double slit, which are separated by $25\mu m$. Due to misalignment of the setup, the light from the bottom slit lags behind the light emanating from the top, with a phase shift of $\frac{\pi}{2}$. An interference pattern is observed on the screen that is $5m$ away. Calculate the angular positions of the $0th, 1st$ and $2nd$ interfecence maxima.

Now, I went for a more "first principle" approach to try and work out the diffraction equation, so I could find the angles.

The logic I used mainly followed the derivation of the fringe maxima under normal circumstances, with the small modification:

The "new path difference" for an arbitrary point P on the screen is $\delta + \frac{\lambda}{4}$, which is equal to $d\sin(\theta)$, where $\delta$ is an arbitrary path difference, and the $\frac{\lambda}{4}$ accounts for the phase lag.

Because of the condition for maxima, I therefore said the path difference must be a whole number of wavelengths, so I fiddled with the fact that:

$$\delta + \frac{\lambda}{4} = d\sin(\theta) = m\lambda$$

I ended up going in circles a little bit from here, not too sure where to proceed, but I thought "oh, it's obvious" and wrote down that for this situation:
$$d\sin(\theta) = \left(m+\frac{1}{4}\right)\lambda$$
To calculate the angular positions.

After discussing with a friend of mine, she said that this didn't take too much sense, as this was showing destructive interference, not constructive.
Upon reviewing my work, I thought, "oh, why did I add the 1/4, the other wave is lagging?" and resolved to
$$d\sin(\theta) = \left(m-\frac{1}{4}\right)\lambda$$

My friend then offered an explanation of "because it's 1/4 of a wavelength behind, you simply need to add 3/4 of a wavelength to the maxima criteria to get 'back in phase' ", which makes sense to me- but I was craving a diagrammatic derivation of this, if possible.

Further, I'm confused as to why my initial attempts weren't providing the (apparent) correct answer of:

$$d\sin(\theta) = \left(m+\frac{3}{4}\right)\lambda$$
At first I thought, because of the off-centre diffraction pattern, this answer and my (2nd) answer must be the same thing, but in a later question:

> Find the linear density of the maxima.

We got ever so slightly differing answers.

Any pointers would really be appreciated! My head is spinning trying to figure it out...

> In general, for a problem like this, would I always calculate as:

$$d\sin(\theta) = \left(m + \text{fraction of } \lambda \text{ corresponding to phase difference}\right)\lambda$$

Answer (score 0):

The phase difference between the light from each of the slits changes by $2\pi$ from one fringe to an adjacent fringe.
Usually the bright fringed formed when there is zero phase difference is called the $m=0$ fringe at position $Y$ in the diagram.
Other bright fringes can be labelled $m = \pm 1,\,\pm2,\,\pm3, . . . . . $.

[image]

If light from the bottom slit $B$ lags behind the light emanating from the top slit $A$ with a phase shift of $\frac \pi 2$ then this corresponds to a shifting of the fringe pattern by $\frac 14$ of a fringe width shown as positions $X$ and $Z$ in the diagram.

Now where is the new zero order fringe, at position $X$ ($m=\frac 34$) or position $Z$ ($m=-\frac 14$)?
I would favour the approach of "speeding up" the arrival of waves from the lagging slit $B$ and the "slowing down" the arrival of waves from slit $A$ which can be done by decreasing path $BY$ and increasing path $AY$ and this corresponds to position $Z$.

For the waves to arrive in phase at position $X$ requires a greater path difference as $BX-AX> AZ-BZ$.

Consider being able to change the phase lag from slit $B$ continuously from zero.
What would you see?
The $m=0$ bright fringe (zero order) would be seen to move down towards position $Z$ whilst the $m=+1$ bright fringe would be moving down towards position $X$.

I read the problem *Calculate the angular positions of the 0th,1st and 2nd interference maxima* as *Calculate the **new** angular positions of the **old** 0th,1st and 2nd interference maxima.*

Comment: So is the (m-1/4) answer correct, or is it 'synonymous' with (m+3/4), depending on the logic you use? As I'm still a little bit lost

Comment: It all depends on the definition of the zeroth interference maximum.

Comment: So if the 0th maximum was along the centreline, would it me (m - 1/4) now then?

Comment: Position Z represents the smallest relative change of the phase of the waves from the two slits.